# Pythin lmfit library: How do I use the minimizer to limit the # of function calls

Tags: python, scipy, lmfit

How do I use the Minimizer object to minimize the # of function calls. I get this message from the logs:

Too many function calls (max set to %i)!  Use: minimize(func, params, ..., maxfev=NNN)or set leastsq_kws[\'maxfev\']  to increase this maximum.'

```
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp, loadtxt
from lmfit import  Model
from lmfit import Minimizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = loadtxt('data/model1d_gauss.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    "1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"
    return (amp/(sqrt(2*pi)*wid)) * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*wid**2))


gmodel = Model(gaussian)

result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=1, wid=1,method= 'least_squares')

print(result.fit_report())

r = result.fit_report()

plt.plot(x, y,         'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[lmfit documentation link](http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#lmfit.minimizer.Minimizer.leastsq)

[Github link](https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py)

I want to make the fitting faster by minimizing the function calls (lots of the data is noisy crap anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i would recommend this, but as you are using scipy's [least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) internally, you could just pass the options needed, e.g.:

```
result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=1, wid=1,method='least_squares',
                    fit_kws={'max_nfev': 100})
```

Of course this assumes, that lmfit will accept the state after observing the `maxiter reached` status. But from your question it sounds, this is treated as warning only.

Keep in mind, that this optimizer is based on tolerance-criterions (see docs) and when not converging given `x` number of steps, it actually *thinks* it can still improve the minimization!

As asked in the comment: yes you can change those criterions too, e.g. by doing:

```
result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=1, wid=1,method='least_squares',
                fit_kws={'ftol': 1-07,   # default 1e-08
                         'xtol': 1-07,   #         1e-08
                         'gtol': 1-07})  #         1e-08
```

Comment: Can you also fit the data until some acceptable error? If so what is the code snippet for that?

Comment: @im281 You can use any parameter, documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html). I added some example.