# lmfit - minimizer does not accept scipy minimizer keyword arguments

Tags: python, scipy, lmfit

I am trying to fit some model to my data with `lmfit`. See the MWE below:

```py
import lmfit
import numpy as np

def lm(params, x):
    slope = params['slope']
    interc = params['interc']

    return interc + slope * x

def lm_min(params, x, data):
    y = lm(params, x)
    return data - y

x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y = lm({'slope':1, 'interc':0.5}, x)

ydata = y + np.random.randn(1000)

params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('slope', 2)
params.add('interc', 1)

fitter = lmfit.Minimizer(lm_min, params, fcn_args=(x, ydata), fit_kws={'xatol':0.01})
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder')
```

In order to be finished earlier (accuracy is not the most important thing for now), I want to change the criteria for stopping the fit. Based on the [docs](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html) and some searches on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801289/7415412), I tried to give some keyword arguments (`fit_kws` in the line below) that will be passed to the minimizer that is used. I also tried to use `kws` and `**{'xatol':0.01}`. Next to that I also tried the before-mentioned options in the last line where I call `fitter.minimize()`. However, in all cases I get a `TypeError`, saying that it got unexpected keyword arguments:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/STACK/WUR/PhD/Experiments/Microclimate experiment/Scripts/Fluctuations/mwe.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 fitter = lmfit.Minimizer(lm_min, params, fcn_args=(x, ydata), fit_kws={'xatol':0.01})
---> 27 fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder')
     28 

~/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
   1924                         val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
   1925                     kwargs['method'] = val
-> 1926         return function(**kwargs)
   1927 
   1928 

~/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in scalar_minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
    906         else:
    907             try:
--> 908                 ret = scipy_minimize(self.penalty, variables, **fmin_kws)
    909             except AbortFitException:
    910                 pass

TypeError: minimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_kws'
```

Does anybody know how I can add keyword arguments for the specific solvers?

#### Version info:

python: 3.6.9
scipy: 1.3.1
lmfit: 0.9.12

Comment: Just pass the dictionary, there is no keyword such as `'fit_kws'`

Comment: As I said, I already tried to pass the dictionary with **{'xatol':0.01}

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean to say dictionary. Just pass `xatol = 0.01` without the `**` it will be received as dictionary `{'xatol':0.01}`

Comment: Also already tried that, gives the same type of error but then for xatol.

Comment: Which version of `lmfit` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to pass keyword arguments to the underlying `scipy` solver would be just to use

```
# Note: valid but will not do what you want
fitter = lmfit.Minimizer(lm_min, params, fcn_args=(x, ydata), xatol=0.01)
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder')
```

or

```
# Also: valid but will not do what you want
fitter = lmfit.Minimizer(lm_min, params, fcn_args=(x, ydata))
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder', xatol=0.01)
```

The main problem here is that `xatol` is not a valid keyword argument for the underlying solver, `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.  Instead, you probably mean to use `tol`:

```
fitter = lmfit.Minimizer(lm_min, params, fcn_args=(x, ydata), tol=0.01)
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder')
```

or

```
fitter = lmfit.Minimizer(lm_min, params, fcn_args=(x, ydata))
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder', tol=0.01)
```

Comment: The first 2 options do not work as I explained before already. The argument tol is indeed excepted and does what I expect. I found another solution, which I will post below. And BTW thanks for changing the title, stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0):

In a github [issue](https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/issues/464) I found the following solution:

```
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder', **{'options':{'xatol':4e-4}})
```

**Update**
As mentioned by @dashesy, this is the same as writing:

```
fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder', options={'xatol':4e-4})
```

This also works for other solver options.

Comment: this is equivalent to `fit = fitter.minimize(method='nelder', options={'xatol':4e-4}})`

Comment: @dashesy: you are right. Updated my answer accordingly.